# How to recompress 2 million gzip files without storing them twice?

Tags: tar, disk-usage, compression, large-files

I have about 2 million (60GiB) of gzipped small files and I would like to create a compressed archive containing all of them in an uncompressed version. Unfortunately, I cannot just uncompress them all and then create the compressed archive as I only have about 70GiB of free disk space. In other words, how can I do an equivalent of `tar --file-filter="zcat" zcf file.tar.gz directory` if the command-line switch like `--file-filter` doesn't exist in GNU tar?

Comment: Do you have a multiprocessor machine?

Comment: @Anthon: not on this machine, but for the future readers we might assume that yes.

Comment: As you have to recompress, there is something gain there. Any particular reason why to use `gzip`? Combining and compressing saves space, but you would gain a lot more if you would compress to an `xz`-ed tar file. Is that an option?

Comment: Any compression program would do. If I can create a tar file of the decompressed-but-not-stored files, I can pipe it to any other program.

Answer (score 6):

An option could be to use [`avfs`](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) (here assuming a GNU system):

```
mkdir ~/AVFS &&
avfsd ~/AVFS &&
cd ~/AVFS/where/your/gz/files/are/ &&
find . -name '*.gz' -type f -printf '%p#\0' |
  tar --null -T - --transform='s/.gz#$//' -cf - | pigz > /dest/file.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 3):

Take note, that this is fragile when it comes to nasty file names.

```
dir_with_small_files=/home/john/files
tmpdir=/tmp/ul/dst
tarfile=/tmp/ul.tar
mkfifo "${tarfile}"

gzip <"${tarfile}" >"${tarfile}.gz" &

find "$dir_with_small_files" -type f | \
while read src; do
    dstdir="${tmpdir}/$(dirname $src)"
    dst="$(basename $src .gz)"
    mkdir -p "$dstdir"
    gunzip <"$src" >"${dstdir}/${dst}"
    # rm "$src" # uncomment to remove the original files
    echo "${dstdir}/${dst}"
done | \
cpio --create --format=ustar -v --quiet 2>&1 >"${tarfile}" | \
while read x; do
    rm "$x"
done

# clean-up
rm "$tarfile"
rm -r "$tmpdir"
```

The files are uncompressed temporarily under `$tmpdir`, passed to `cpio` then as soon as they're added to the archive, removed.

Comment: Also, if you have multi-threads, I would suggest using `pigz` as an alternative to gzip :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I tried so far - it seems to work, but is terribly slow, even with PyPy:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tarfile
import os
import gzip
import sys
import cStringIO

tar = tarfile.open("/dev/stdout", "w|")
for name in sys.stdin:
    name = name[:-1]  # remove the trailing newline
    try:
        f = gzip.open(name)
        b = f.read()
        f.close()
    except IOError:
        f = open(name)
        b = f.read()
        f.close()
    # the [2:] there is to remove ./ from "find" output
    ti = tarfile.TarInfo(name[2:])
    ti.size = len(b)
    io = cStringIO.StringIO(b)
    tar.addfile(ti, io)
tar.close()
```

Usage: `find . | script.py | gzip > file.tar.gz`

Comment: Uncompressing and especially recompressing on a disk which is almost full, is going to be slow, no matter what.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: I measured without `|gzip` and the uncompressed file didn't basically touch the HDD, so IMHO it shouldn't be THAT slow.

Comment: De and Recompressing is done in optimised C code in CPython. There might be buffering involved that cause the disc not to be touched.

Comment: find . -exec cat \{\} \; > /dev/null should provide a lower bound on the amount of time this operation could possibly take.  I would imagine that part of your problem is the creation of a bunch of large python objects containing your files in both compressed and uncompressed forms and then letting the garbage collector clean up after yourself.  see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115066/how-much-time-is-the-garbage-collector-using

Comment: You could probably save some memory by [figuring out the uncompressed size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1704458/12892) and passing to `tar` the gzip file like object.